# resize simpledialog2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, hybrid

I am using [simpledialog2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html) in hybrid android development. I wanted to know is there any way to resize a dialog before display, due to some extra content the dialog is not fitting in screen in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1):

simpleDialog2 have size and position options:

```
zindex: CSS zIndex
width: CSS width
left: CSS left
top: CSS top
```

You can find them directly here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/options.html

And here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kzxS9/